# Как посчитать количество символов в строке в python?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть таблица, в ней есть столбец с названиями песен (сам столбец называется `song_name`). 
Надо найти **`5`** самых которых названий (по символам) и **`5`** самых длинных. 
С помощью каких команд можно посчитать количество символов в каждой строке и выбрать 5 самых коротких и 5 самых длинных?

```
from google.colab import drive   # загружаем специальную библиотеку

drive.mount('/content/drive')    # авторизуемся

import pandas as pd              # импорт библиотеки pandas. в будущем обращение к этой библиотеке будет происходить по сокращённому имени pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/dannye_1.xlsx')

# ??? df
```

Comment: Добавьте код решения вашей задачи, с указанием конкретного затруднения в её решении.

Answer (score 0):

Можно записать все ваши песни в массив отсортировать лист по возрастанию и с помощью срезов взять нужные 5 слов.

```
  strings = ["слово", "буква", "меч", "автомобиль", "трактор", "я", "ты", 
  "какашки",'элеватор','транзистор',"электроэнцефалография"]
  result= sorted(strings,key=len)
  print('sort result: ',result)

  # sort result: ['я', 'ты', 'меч', 'слово', 'буква', 'трактор', 'какашки', 
  'элеватор', 'автомобиль', 'транзистор', 'электроэнцефалография'] # 11 слов

  # 5 cамых коротких
  shorts = result[:5]
  print('shorts:',shorts)

  # shorts: ['я', 'ты', 'меч', 'слово', 'буква']

  # 5 cамых длинных
  arr = result[6:]
  longs = arr[::-1]
  print('longs: ',longs)

  # longs:  ['электроэнцефалография', 'транзистор', 'автомобиль', 'элеватор', 'какашки']
```